# Codeigniter Route not working on live server though works on localhost

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Following route in Codeigniter is not working on demo server
But it works on locahost. Can you see any issue in this?

```
$route['forge/deleteBucket/(:any)'] = 'ForgeAPI/deleteBucket/$1';
```

**ERROR**
An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException Message: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see [link]curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html[/link])

*Why curl needs ssl? Must be something that I do not know*

Best Regards

Comment: What error you are getting, on live server which OS you have.

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException

Message: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see [link]https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html[/link])

Answer (score 1):

Check these options in cURL

1. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST is set to 0
2. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to false

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared any specific error reporting you are getting.So I am listing some of the possibilities it might be:

1. Placement of the $route['forge/deleteBucket/(:any)'] = 'ForgeAPI/deleteBucket/$1'; in the route file
2. Controller may not uploaded to the server

So if you can share more details of the error I can help on that.

Comment: Thx for the response... updated the post